# Why are there so many more dual-band (2.4 & 5 GHz) Wi-Fi APs than single-band, 5GHz-only ones?

Tags: router, wireless, ieee-802.11

Why are so many more dual band (802.11n 2.4GHz & 802.11ac 5 GHz) APs than single-band, 5GHz-only ones? Is this for backwards compatibility?

Comment: Because that's what people want to buy.  so that's what they sell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are so many more dual band (802.11n 2.4GHz & 802.11ac 5 GHz) APs than single-band, 5GHz-only ones? Is this for backwards compatibility?

2.4GHz support is required by the standard. Until the 802.11ac ammendment, 5GHz support was optional.

So to follow the standard, either a device needed to be single band 2.4GHz, or dual band. Anything on the market that *only* supports 5GHz (i.e. does not have the capability to support 2.4GHz in the hardware) is not IEEE standard compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Legacy is the only reason I can think of. 
2.4GHz was standard before the 5Ghz channel came to the scene. There are many APs that work on 2.4GHz only.